# Expose files to public via rewrite

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm using nginx docker engine for a symfony app, and I have some images under `/var/www/html/project/ezplatform/files/(.*)` that i need to expose them to the public.
I tried to add under my nginx configuration this rewrite config:

```
rewrite "^/var/www/html/project/ezplatform/files/(.*)" "/app.php" break;
rewrite "^/var/www/html/project/ezplatform/files/(.*)" "/var/www/html/project
/ezplatform/files/$1" break;
```

But still facing an exception `404 Not Found` when I try to access to an available image.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a location block to your nginx conf, where you define a handle for the images directory, which nginx then uses to retrieve files from the full path. Like:

```
location /other_images/ {
alias /var/www/html/project/ezplatform/files/;
}
```

You can link to the images using your 'virtual' folder path: 
`other_images/example.gif`

(So in HTML, `<img src = "other_images/example.gif">`, or use whatever the symfony syntax is for image links.)

Let me know if this solves the `404 Not Found` problem.

Comment: yes without adding rewrite, since this method just makes nginx locate the images and serve them to public

Comment: didnt work this is my nginx logs : /06/21 09:56:38 [error] 8#8: *71 open() "/var/www/html/project/ezplatform/web/var/www/html/project/ezplatform/files/a.jpg"

Comment: Oh it's starting from `/web`. So the web directory is set as root somewhere. If you don't mind pasting the whole conf file for the project, it might be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: That's it it's set to root. Ok my project is a project based on ezplatform, I have the same nginx configuration  https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform/tree/master/doc/nginx

Comment: You could try setting a root for the `files` directory location, so it might not look in the default `web` root for those files: 
`location /files/ {
    root /var/www/html/project/ezplatform;
}`

This would go just underneath the default root line (`root /var/www/ezinstall/web;`) in the config. Don't set an alias location like my previous answer if you're going to try this though.

Comment: could update your answer by giving some information about code lines (where i gonna add your conf) based on the github link